# Python matplotlib graph data persists with iPython kernal

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have an application that allows the user to make some vertical line plots among other data. Since I need to use multiple graphs (on multiple pages of a ttk.notebook), I created a class that handles all the gui elements needed to achieve my goals. When I launched the class as its own application things were fine. Once I added the class to my larger gui I encountered an error: the lines created by the user persist as long as the iPython kernal remains open.

I have two questions:

1. What is causing the new lines to persist on my graph?
2. Will the issue persist once I turn the larger gui into a standalone executable?

Edit: I've added some code as suggested by j_4321. Its not the exact code but I feel I have the important bits listed. I'm having some trouble making my own executable so I'm still working on that.

Edit 2: The Sequel

Thanks to j_4321 for being patient. I Have updated the code. The error occurs when the classes are in different files (maybe only). This may be a solution to my problem but being that I am new to Python I'd still like to understand what the deal is.

sample.py:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Notebook
from Sample1 import ContainsPlot

class MainUserInterface(Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.grid()
            self.parent = parent
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
           plotsTab = Notebook(self, name ='controlTab') #create notebook in the GUI
           plotsTab.grid(column = 1, row =0, columnspan = 5, rowspan = 14)
           plotsFrame = Frame(plotsTab, name = "plotsFrame")
           plotsFrame.grid(column = 1, row = 0, rowspan = 14)
           plotsTab.add(plotsFrame, text = "ContainsPlot class lives here")
           plotFrameElements = ContainsPlot(plotsFrame)
           plotFrameElements.grid(column =0, row = 0)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = MainUserInterface(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample1.py:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Frame
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
#from matplotlib import cbook
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,\
 NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class ContainsPlot(Frame, object):
    TestFig = Figure(figsize = (5,5), dpi = 100, tight_layout = True)
    TestPlotA = TestFig.add_subplot(111)
    dist = range(0,10)
    dataListA = range(0,10)
    TestPlotA.plot(dist, dataListA)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        TestPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.TestFig, self)
        TestPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(column = 2, row = 0, columnspan = 3,\
            rowspan = 4)
        TestFrame = Frame(self)
        TestFrame.grid(column = 2, row =6, columnspan = 3)
        nuToolbar = PlotToolbar(TestPlot, TestFrame, self)
        nuToolbar.update()

class PlotToolbar(NavigationToolbar2TkAgg, object):
    toolitems = [t for t in NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.toolitems if
        t[0] in ('Home', 'Pan', 'Zoom', 'Save')]
    toolitems.append(('Add Vert Line', 'Add Line', 'move', 'AddLine'))

    def __init__(self, plotCanvas, frame, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.fig = plotCanvas.figure
        for foo in self.fig.axes:
            self.ax = foo
        NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.__init__(self, plotCanvas, frame)

    def AddLine(self):
        yMin, yMax = self.ax.get_ylim()
        self.parent.TestPlotA.axvline(x = 3, ymin = yMin, ymax = yMax, color = 'm')
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
```

To reproduce the bug, click the "add line" button (the rightmost) and close the Gui Window. Launch the program again and the line persists. I am using spyder to run my program. Thanks!

Comment: 1. would be easier to check with a code sample to run, and for 2., you should try first and then edit your question to tell us what happened.

Comment: 1. Added Sample code.
2. Having some issues getting my .c Python file to compile. Will update when I have something working

Comment: I looked at your sample of code, but cannot figure out how to obtain something with it. So please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and give us an example that show us what's wrong when it's executed.

Comment: Updated the code again. This one will run, pinky swear!